Raw socket receives no data from source on current device, python socket library
I am using this library to sniff data regarding market orders in a computer game: https://github.com/hrichharms/AlbiPy
It is currently working well on my computer with a fresh Windows 10. When I tried to launch the same program which is working with this library on my laptop, I figured out it doesn't sniff any data. It is also Windows 10 there.
On my PC there is a wire ethernet connection, meanwhile on laptop it is wireless.
I am still trying to find solution why it doesn't work on the laptop and hope you can help me.

I tried to install latest .NET framework, but is it already installed.
Also tried to turn off Windows Firewall, it didn't help.
Tried installing NpCap, no result


as I remember usually sniffing need to use special library pcap which can catch all information send to computer (even if it not addressed for this computer). Other problem is if network use very old Hub (which send all information to all devices in network) or Switch or Router which filter data and will not send it to other computers. And then computer has to work between other computers as man in the middle. Or it may need to "poison" switch and it will send data to your computer.

In this case i'd use mobile network to check. However, I tried and still got no result.
Before reinstalling Windows, I tried to install npcap and it gave me no result. Now trying again. Unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem.

if you want to check what is doing other computer (connected by wire to switch) then problem is switch because it tries to send data only between source computer and target computer and it doesn't send information to other computers in local network - it has special table to keep IPs and MAC addresses to check where it has to send it - and ncap can't change it. If switch would send information to other computers then ncap can catch it. But It may need to "poison" switch (to fill this table with fake IPs and MACs). If you use wifi then it may also need something more than only ncap.

if you want to see all connections on own computer then it may need to install ncap and use tools like wireshark to collect all packages

https://www.wireshark.org/
